# How to download file from ftp?

Tags: python, file, ftp, windows-xp, installation

I'm scripting an install script in python.

How do I download file from ftp in python?

Operating system -- Windows XP - if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code snippet I'm currently using.

```
import mimetypes
import os
import urllib2
import urlparse

def filename_from_url(url):
    return os.path.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(url)[2])

def download_file(url):
    """Create an urllib2 request and return the request plus some useful info"""
    name = filename_from_url(url)
    r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
    info = r.info()
    if 'Content-Disposition' in info:
        # If the response has Content-Disposition, we take filename from it
        name = info['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
        if name[0] == '"' or name[0] == "'":
            name = name[1:-1]
    elif r.geturl() != url:
        # if we were redirected, take the filename from the final url
        name = filename_from_url(r.geturl())
    content_type = None
    if 'Content-Type' in info:
        content_type = info['Content-Type'].split(';')[0]
    # Try to guess missing info
    if not name and not content_type:
        name = 'unknown'
    elif not name:
        name = 'unknown' + mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type) or ''
    elif not content_type:
        content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
    return r, name, content_type
```

Usage:

```
req, filename, content_type = download_file('http://some.url')
```

Then you can use `req` as a file-like object and e.g. use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the file contents into a local file. If the MIME type doesn't matter simply remove that part of the code.

Since you seem to be lazy, here's code downloading the file directly to a local file:

```
import shutil
def download_file_locally(url, dest):
    req, filename, content_type = download_file(url)        
    if dest.endswith('/'):
        dest = os.path.join(dest, filename)
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(req, f)
    req.close()
```

This method is smart enough to use the filename sent by the server if you specify a path ending with a slash, otherwise it uses the destination you specified.

Comment: Can you give an easier option?

Comment: Seriously? What's easier than just using copy&paste to have a single-line function call?

Comment: Where do I enter the file name?

Answer (score 6):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
req = urlopen('ftp://ftp.gnu.org/README')
```

Then you can use `req.read()` to load the file content into a variable or do anything else with it, or `shutil.copyfileobj` to save the content to a disk without loading it to memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)

Code Sample from the documentation:

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('ftp.cwi.nl')   # connect to host, default port
>>> ftp.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
>>> ftp.retrlines('LIST')     # list directory contents
total 24418
drwxrwsr-x   5 ftp-usr  pdmaint     1536 Mar 20 09:48 .
dr-xr-srwt 105 ftp-usr  pdmaint     1536 Mar 21 14:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp-usr  pdmaint     5305 Mar 20 09:48 INDEX
 .
 .
 .
>>> ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
try:
    req = urlopen('ftp://ftp.expasy.org/databases/enzyme/enzclass.txt')
except:
    print ("Error")
```