# downloading files with Python through FTP

Tags: python, url, unix, download

I can think of three ways to download a file from an `ftp://` address from python: using `urllib` (or `urllib2`), using `ftplib`, or by making an `os.system` call to a common program like `wget`. Assume that I am trying to do this only on unix systems. Are there strong reasons to prefer one method over the other? In particular, `urllib` versus `ftplib`? `urllib` seems much simpler to use. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy to download ftp file using python check the python doc:
http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html

btw somebody already asked that here: [How to download file from ftp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006574/how-to-download-file-from-ftp)